# Why did Russia set up so many cities in Siberia and Far East?

Tags: 19th-century, russia

If one takes a casual glance at the Russian population census data, he or she would be astonished to find that a significant part of the Russian population is actually not concentrated west of the Urals but fairly spread out in its Siberia and Far East federal districts. This clearly doesn't make sense economically, as these locations are too inland and the rivers they are sitting on only flow into the Arctic oceans, so transportation relies almost solely on the Trans-Siberian Railway, which was built in the late 19th century.

As a hunch, this almost seems like some sort of planned colonization to me, with many cities of highly similar metallurgy/heavy equipment manufacturing industry as the base of the economy with a population around 100,000 to 1,000,000. To me, this almost feels like the original 13 colonies of colonial America. What was the historical reason behind this seemingly half-successful colonization? Why was Russia so insistent in putting people into its vast interior, where it was absolutely safe from enemy invasion and not worth invasion or even nuclear strikes anyway, as opposed to just establishing big military outposts and mining/oil towns like in Alaska?

Comment: Maybe you can describe more some assumptions. Even though Siberia had planned colonization (for example, industries moved during WWII http://michaeltfassbender.com/nonfiction/the-world-wars/big-picture/the-transfer-of-soviet-factories-during-world-war-ii/ and ) that explain your question, Siberia also has many natural resources as well. A human settlement not only needs to be a trade post well connected.

Comment: Even some basic research will tell you that only 23% of population lives in Asia (eg very small part), which includes the original native population, too. From Wikipedia: “the Russian Far East one of the most sparsely populated areas in the world.” That being said Siberia is aboundant of natural resources, and Far East has strategic ports, fishing etc.

Comment: It may help to know that [Russian conquest of Siberia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_conquest_of_Siberia) dates back to 1580 and reached the Pacific in 1639.

Comment: @Greg That sounds like Wyoming having 5 million people.

Comment: For reference, [Siberia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siberia) a population density of 2.7 people per sq. kilometer, which is [about the same](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_population_density) as Montana and half a person more than Wyoming.

Comment: The movement of industry east of the Urals in WW2 is well documented. Raw materials are there also, so that is where the mines are.

Comment: Even before the war and the eastward move of critical production facilities, the [Five-Year Plans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-year_plans_for_the_national_economy_of_the_Soviet_Union) *were*, indeed, planned industrialization.

Comment: Humm... Denver, Alberquerque, Phoenix, Salt Lake City, Reno... All well inland, and without navigable rivers.  And while Wyoming may not have 5 million people, Arizona & Colorado do.

Comment: It was indeed intentional colonization. But if you give any reference on population statistics, this will help answering the question. What population data did you use?

Comment: I made the question historical by casting it in the past tense and alluding to the 19th century, and have voted to reopen it in its current form.

Comment: I am not "astonished" enough to vote to reopen.

Comment: Question still provides no evidence to back the assertions. This isn't a question, it is a request to discuss a theory without evidence.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues:

As to "how" the establishment of cities in Siberia came about, the Russian/Soviet governments paid much higher wages to [workers](https://www.brookings.edu/articles/siberia-communist-megalomania/) living in those cities, plus (in the case of the Soviets) priority in getting living quarters west of the Urals in their old age.

As to "why," Russia wanted to establish control over large land areas and resources as a buffer zone against invasions, e.g. the Mongolians or Chinese from the east, or as an "escape hatch" from European invaders such as the Nazis.

Comment: Seems plausible but any sources or evidence to support this?

Comment: @LarsBosteen: I found, and linked a source (to the word, workers) that confirmed this. If you want to see more answers, will you cast the last vote to reopen?

Comment: I already cast my vote to reopen (the 4th one)! Let's hope someone else comes along...

Comment: @TomAu Gotcha reopen vote, right here! #5

Comment: @axsvl77: Thanks.

Comment: And of course they both used convict labour and forced migration to the area to both settle the far east and get rid of malcontents and criminals in the core regions in the west.

Answer (score -2):

Many can state that the population there can be considered more than it should logically be.

It doesn't make sense economically, but it does strategically.

Colonization and planned industrialization made sure that population does evolve in areas that are not strategically viable to be attacked and occupied like many border areas.

That is one of the reasons why any attacking army from Napoleon to WW2 did not manage to defeat them. It's one thing to invade and clean most of everything up to the Urals and it's an entirely different exponential resources requirement to cover all the land.

Comment: Sources would improve this answer; this reads as an argued opinion, rather than a researched answer.

Comment: Why would the population east of the Urals be considered to be "more than it should logically be"?  You have open, largely unpopulated lands: why would people not logically want to move there?  Compare with the US west (excluding the Pacific Coast): much of it is desert or rugged mountains, yet a considerable number of people have moved there.

Comment: Your comment does not make any sense. Move there to do what ? Most do not want to move to such areas no matter what country are you talking about. Take a look at the US geographical distribution: https://www.visualcapitalist.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/144-largest-counties-50-percent-population-us2.png Half the population in the US lives in 5% of the space and another half the rest of 95%.

Comment: @jamesqf a large part of the people who moved into Siberia in the late imperial and most of the Soviet eras were forced migrants. Internal exiles, convict labour, and the guards for them.

Comment: @Overmind: Well, that's half the population that wants to live in 95% of the space, no?  And with the US, you also have the fact that a lot of the space in the intermountain west is desert, so population is limited to places where there's water.  Not AFAIK an issue in most of Siberia.  (And as as someone who does live in the 95% of the space, "to do what" includes hiking, skiing, climbing mountains, riding bikes or my horse...)

Comment: @jwenting: Of course you have different governments.  Unlike the US, which encouraged westward migration with the Homestead Act &c, under the Imperial & Soviet governments, migration was discouraged unless forced - and those who could move, mostly moved OUT.  (Often to the US, ironically.)  But my point remains: you have a lot of good land open to settlement (and from what I've seen, much of Siberia seems rather nice, if you avoid the flat parts), so why is it surprising that people move there?

Comment: @jamesqf ever been to Siberia? It looks nice on NatGeo videos, but it isn't. No infrastructure, no nothing, most of it is a mosquito swamp in summer and a deep freeze in winter. Many expeditions sent there suffered extremely high losses from exposure, disease, and starvation. Add to that that the population in Russia and the USSR wasn't mobile because of travel restrictions, and you have a place where nobody goes unless they're forced to at gunpoint.

Comment: @jwenting: No, I don't speak Russian.  But I can't see that Siberia overall is much different than Canada & Alaska.  Of course some places are nicer than others - FTM parts of Maine & Minnesota are boggy & full of mosquitos & black flies in summer, and get a bit chilly in winter.  I think your key point is the travel restrictions: the Russians didn't want their peasants/proletariat moving to places where they couldn't easily be controlled.